# pre-selected items in tree in angular 9 and angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

i create tree in angular material and angular 9 .

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tree-mateiral-multilevel?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

but i have a problem . i have items in my items my  be have child or not.

when I create a tree every items not having any child get pre-selected, but I dont need do this .

```
    rolesToTree(roles): void {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(roles))
    const selections: ItemFlatNode[] = [];
    const controllers = [];
    roles.forEach(element => {
        const attrs = [];
        element['children'].forEach(attr => {
            const secAttrs = [];
                attr['children'].forEach(sec => {
                    const secAction = { name: sec['title'], actionId: sec['id'] };
                    secAttrs.push(secAction);
                    if (sec['selected'] === true) {
                        const a = new ItemFlatNode(false, sec['id'], sec['title'], 3);
                        selections.push(a);
                    }
                });
            if (attr['selected'] === true) {
                const a = new ItemFlatNode(false, attr['id'], attr['title'], 2);
                selections.push(a);
            }
            const actionss = { name: attr['title'], actionId: attr['id'], children: secAttrs };
            attrs.push(actionss);
        });
        const controller = { name: element['title'], actionId: element['id'], children: attrs };
        controllers.push(controller);
    });
    // this.checklistSelection = new SelectionModel<ItemFlatNode>(true, selections);
    this.defualtSelected = selections;

    const data = [{ name: 'All', actionId: 'sds', children: controllers }];
    this.database.dataChange.next(this.database.builTree(data, 0));
}
```

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ????**

Comment: wrong stackblitz path. fix that

Comment: @GouravGarg i fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method descendantsAllSelected verifies for every child node is selected, which will return true if there is no descendant element.

To fix that, need to check for descendants length and if that is 0, return node node selected value.

Update descendantsAllSelected method as below:

```
    descendantsAllSelected(node: ItemFlatNode): boolean {
       const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
       return (this.checklistSelection.isSelected(node) && descendants.length==0) || (descendants.length>0 && descendants.every(child => this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child)));
     }
```

Comment: hi Gourav , help on this please , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191974/to-open-angular-material-tooltip-above-when-the-page-is-scrolled-and-avoid-the-t , thanks